# Feature Testing using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Can somebody please explain me how can I use JMeter for Feature testing?

I'm able to create multiple HTTP requests within a Testplan. But I need know the way to capture the previous API response and pass one of the response data to the next API request.

Eg:
1.Create Account.
Request- POST: /account
Response: ID: "Value"

2. Read account 
   Request- GET: /account/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter is really more of a load testing tool, and best used as such. Capturing data from responses is possible using the [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html), which can store extracted values in variables for use in a subsequent request. It is a bit of a pain in the ass to use, though.

On your request, add a Regular Expression Extractor:

```
Field to check: body
Reference name: EXAMPLE
Regular Expression: \[.*\] #your regex here, stuff in square brackets as example
Match No.: 1
```

In a subsequent request, you can then use the variables defined by the extractor, e.g. `${EXAMPLE_g0}` for the entire match, or `${EXAMPLE_g1}` for group 1, etc.